# Make pygame draw cubes wherever the user clicks

Tags: python, pygame, draw

I want to make a kind of "level editor" as an exercise.
I've got this code:

```
import pygame

running = True
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 500))

class Cube:
    def update(self):
        self.cx, self.cy = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        self.square = pygame.Rect(self.cx, self.cy, 50, 50)

    def draw(self): 
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), self.square)

cube = Cube()
drawing_cube = False
drawing_cube2 = False

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            cube.update()
            drawing_cube = True

    screen.fill((0, 255, 0))
    if drawing_cube:
        cube.draw()
    pygame.display.flip()


pygame.quit()
```

However, it doesn't create multiple squares; it just re-locates the already created square.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's doing exactly what you told it to do: update the one and only `Cube` object in the game, and then redraw the screen and that one object.  If you want multiple cubes, you have to create each one.  Perhaps something like this:

```
cube_list = []          # List of all cubes

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:   # Make a new cube
            cube = Cube()
            cube.update()
            cube_list.append(cube)
            drawing_cube = True

    screen.fill((0, 255, 0))
    if drawing_cube:           #New cube made; draw them all.
        for cube in cube_list:
            cube.draw()

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Now, as an exercise for the student, can you simplify this so that it merely adds the most recent cube to the existing screen, instead of redrawing the entire game area for each new cube?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Prune! but for anyone that is reading this after me, here is the full code:

```
import pygame

cube_list = []
running = True
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 500))

class Cube:
    def update(self):
        self.cx, self.cy = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        self.square = pygame.Rect(self.cx, self.cy, 50, 50)

    def draw(self): 
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), self.square)

cube = Cube()
drawing_cube = False
drawing_cube2 = False

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:   # Make a new cube
            cube = Cube()
            cube.update()
            cube_list.append(cube)
            drawing_cube = True

    screen.fill((0, 255, 0))
    if drawing_cube:           #New cube made; draw them all.
        for cube in cube_list:
            cube.draw()

    pygame.display.flip()


pygame.quit()
```

Cheers!

P.S I've marked your answer as accepted